# Getting error while using df.show() when using user defined function in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this sample dataframe

```
import datetime
elevDF = sc.parallelize([
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 1, 638.55),
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 2, 638.55),
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 3, 638.55),
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 4, 638.55),
    (datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 1, 0, 0), 5, 638.55)
]).toDF(["date", "hour", "value"])
```

I want to make a df with month names as string from datetimes in this column.

This is what I tried

```
## Creating udf function
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import month
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
udfGetMonthName = F.udf(lambda col: month(col), StringType())

## Using udf function
elevDF.select(
    udfGetMonthName('date').alias('year')
).show()
```

However when I run the code I get the following error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1407.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 86.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 86.0 (TID 645, spark-m.asia-south1-c.c.cp-vision-239212.internal, executor 1)
```

I looked at the following link suggestion which suggested that it might be an instance problem ([Issue with df.show() in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641328/issue-with-df-show-in-pyspark)). Restarted the kernel, created new instance. Did not work.

Could anyone please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot use pyspark native functions inside UDF's. It's a way to distribute python functions.

However, you can try to do this using `strftime` which is a python `datetime` library function:

```
elevUDF = F.udf(lambda x: x.strftime("%B"))

elevDF.withColumn("month_name", elevUDF("date")).show()
+-------------------+----+------+----------+
|               date|hour| value|month_name|
+-------------------+----+------+----------+
|1984-01-01 00:00:00|   1|638.55|   January|
|1984-01-01 00:00:00|   2|638.55|   January|
|1984-01-01 00:00:00|   3|638.55|   January|
|1984-01-01 00:00:00|   4|638.55|   January|
|1984-01-01 00:00:00|   5|638.55|   January|
+-------------------+----+------+----------+
```